# Sending the array data in jquery get ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how we can send the `Javascript` array as a parameter in the `ajax` get call.
I am working with the API call and i have the API call method that has three parameters and the third one is the array.

Comment: use jQuery.parseJSON function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
demArray = [];
demArray[0] = 'hi';
demArray[1] = 'hello';
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data: {arrayDem:demArray},
   url: "someUrl",
   success: function(response){

   }
});
```

Also `serialize()` & `serializeArray()` can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting those arrays from a form you could:

```
var form = $('#form').serialize();
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data: form,
   url: "foo.php",
   success: function(data){ 
   }
});
```

Else you could just pass the parameters into `data:` like:

```
data: {foo:Array}
```